# dhclient does not send DHCPv6 Solicit message on disconnect/connect, keeps old lease

Tags: network-manager, ipv6, dhclient, dhcpv6

Network background: Connecting to an IPv4/IPv6 native dual-stack network on a campus with multiple VLAN's and network segments. Using only stateful DHCPv6 with no SLAAC permitted.

When disconnecting and connecting to different network segments with different IPv6 DHCPv6 scopes and prefixes, Network Manager and/or dhclient only send out DHCPv6 Confirm messages to the DHCPv6 server for the previous lease, which is often times incorrect, and uses that previous address on the local interface, rendering IPv6 connectivity broken, even though the DHCPv6 server does not respond (to the Confirm messages). A DHCPv6 Solicit message is never sent to acquire a new lease on the new segment, which the DHCPv6 server would respond to.

Expected/desired behavior would be to send a a DHCPv6 Solicit message (starting the whole DHCPv6 address request process over) if/when the DHCPv6 Confirm messages fail, or more ideally, on every new connect, similar to the behavior for DHCPv4, which works fine. Without this behavior, IPv6 connectivity is either a) broken when changing network segments (possibly moving from one conference room to another) or b) experiencing a lengthy delay in IPv6 connectivity waiting on a DHCPv6 Solicit message to be sent out by the client.

I've confirmed with packet captures that my client does not send out Solicit messages consistently. It does send out Confirm messages consistently upon initial connection.

Not sure if this issue is with dhclient, or Network Manager (using the default Automatic method and settings) passing the old lease information to dhclient under the hood. It may also be a behavior with dhclient listening for RA's that may come from the same local router address on both segments (since it is typically the same router serving both segments), causing dhclient to assume it is on the same local segment at each connection.

It is super irritating that my IPv4 address updates on the new segment immediately as expected, and IPv6 is assigned the previous address resulting in broken IPv6 connectivity, even though DHCPv6 is working just fine.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated. If someone can confirm, I'll file a bug against dhclient and/or Network Manager.

Xubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

my solution for it is to remove the lease file which you can see in ps command. The solicit will be send after dhcpc is restarted.